# hover and freeze then action

Tags: jquery, hover, settimeout

I have a contact page with three pictures and when you hover a picture a text about this pic will be shown in a separate box. The problem is that them you move your mouse quickly around (hovering two or three pictures in a second) all the descriptions are shown in a mess.

Is there some way to make it so that when you hover the picture and only if a pointer stays frozen for let's say one sec, then the text will be displayed?

and the jQcode is:

```
$('#pic1').mouseenter(function() {
myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
if (hidden2.hasClass("active") ){hidden2.fadeOut(200).removeClass('active').css('display','none');}
if (hidden3.hasClass("active") ){hidden3.fadeOut(200).removeClass('active').css('display','none');}

    hidden1.fadeIn(900).addClass('active');
}, 1500);
    });

$('#pic2').mouseenter(function() {
myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
if (hidden1.hasClass("active") ){hidden1.fadeOut(200).removeClass('active').css('display','none');}
if (hidden3.hasClass("active") ){hidden3.fadeOut(200).removeClass('active').css('display','none');}

    hidden2.fadeIn(900).addClass('active');
}, 1500);
    });

$('#pic3').mouseenter(function() {
myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    if (hidden1.hasClass("active") ){hidden1.fadeOut(200).removeClass('active').css('display','none');}
    if (hidden2.hasClass("active") ){hidden2.fadeOut(200).removeClass('active').css('display','none');}

    hidden3.fadeIn(900).addClass('active');
}, 1500);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the hoverIntent plugin : http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js

Here is a few docs : http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

```
$('#pic1').hoverIntent({
    over: function () {
        if (hidden2.hasClass("active") ){
            hidden2.fadeOut(200).removeClass('active').css('display','none');
        }
        if (hidden3.hasClass("active") ){
            hidden3.fadeOut(200).removeClass('active').css('display','none');
        }
        hidden1.fadeIn(900).addClass('active');
    },
    out: function () {
        // Do something when mouseOut
    },
    //selector: '.aClass',
    timeout: 10, // Timer before executing out function
    interval: 1000 // Timer before executing over function
});
```

I'm not too sure about interval option... but just do some tests.